# How to create multiple NgModules and multiple *.html pages in one Angular 2 application

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating Angular2 payroll application which has multiple *.html pages (one for accountants, one for employee manager, one for employee self-service), but which shares the same modules and also some of the same components. Is it possible to create such Angular2 application with multiple *.html pages?

As I am experimenting, I am receiving lot of errors:

```
index_employee.html:16 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8080/traceur
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8080/traceur
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/traceur
    Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:8080/app/scripts/components/employeeprofile.component.js
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/app/scripts/components/employeeprofile.component.js as "./scripts/components/employeeprofile.component" from http://localhost:8080/app/employeesite.module.jsrrr(anonymous function) @ index_employee.html:16
```

and

```
core.umd.js:3376 Error: The selector did not match any elements 
core.umd.js:3376 Error: The selector "s5-employeeprofile" did not match any elements
```

I am tired of catching errors one by one and I would like to know the best practices of building such application:

- Should I write multiple `platform.bootstrapModule(EmployeeSiteModule);` statements in main.ts - one for each module?
- Should I create separate routes for each @NgModule?

Comment: Why would you need multiple pages, why not use one and change the route?

Comment: Multiple pages and multiple NgModules can be useful for economy of resources. I am afraid that one big NgModule which contain tens or hundreds/housands (for big ERP application) of components will be inefficient. I would like to separate pages and modules but use the shared components, services and model classes. But - the question is good! Maybe it is the best practice for Angular2 to use only one Module notwithstaning the number of components which it imports...

Comment: And, of course, I would like to have completely different layouts, menus and other functionality for the different pages. E.g accountants need completely different menus than employees for the self-service application. The question is about modular design and reuse of Angular 2 code.